# Background hover text

Tags: hover, background-color

I cant post image. so here is the reference. when you hover over text it goes background yellow

```css
.highlight {
    margin-left: 20em;
    width: 40%;
margin-top: 5em;
height: 100%;
position:absolute ;
display: inline-block;
flex: 1;
flex-direction: column;
}

.highlight .feature {
    align-items: center;
}

.thumbnail {
    max-width:100% ;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-left: 1em;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
}

.feature h1 {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 0.5em;

}

.feature {
text-align: left;
line-height: 1.75rem;
}

.feature a{
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.feature:hover {
    background-color: yellow;

}
```

```html
<div class="highlight">



        <div class="feature">
            <a href="#" target="_parent">
                <h1>Title Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo sapiente minima maxime. Dicta
                    similique
                    expedita quisquam
                </h1>

                <img class="thumbnail"
                    src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1516245834210-c4c142787335?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1169&q=80"
                    alt="bitcoin">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

https://people.com/

how do I make this yellow background hover only appear behind the text with spacing between the lines.
I've tried many ways but to no luck.

HELP!!!

EDIT: I cant post images. I need 10 reputation